# GeoJSON LineString not appearing on the map using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, leaflet

I have the following HTML div that loads up a map

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

And below is how I load the map up to my html div

```js
const map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', { attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors' }).addTo(map);
// add a topography layer and a places layer
const basemaps = {
   StreetView: L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',   {attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}),
       Topography: L.tileLayer.wms('http://ows.mundialis.de/services/service?',   {layers: 'TOPO-WMS'}),
       Places: L.tileLayer.wms('http://ows.mundialis.de/services/service?', {layers: 'OSM-Overlay-WMS'})
};
//options layer menu button 
L.control.layers(basemaps).addTo(map);
//choose the default layer
basemaps.Topography.addTo(map);
```

I then use the following Ajax call to draw my line strings on the map.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
   var ajaxResponse = jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: "https://www.movebank.org/movebank/service/public/json?study_id=2911040&individual_local_identifiers=4262-84830876&individual_local_identifiers=1163-1163&individual_local_identifiers=2131-2131&sensor_type=gps",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {
            return JSON.stringify(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
           alert(xhr.statusText)                    
        }
        }).done(function(data) {
           let lat;
           let lng;
           let coordinates;
               var result = [];
               const individual = data.individuals[0].locations;            
                        
           individual.forEach((i) => {
              lat = i.location_lat;
                  lng = i.location_long;
                  coordinates = [lng, lat];
                  result.push(coordinates);
               });
```

The ajax call will eventually feed into the following function leading to finally parsing values through the L.geoJSON function as shown below.

```js
var myLines = [{
   "type": "LineString",
   "coordinates": result
}];
L.geoJSON(myLines).addTo(map)
```

You'd expect since there weren't any errors while debugging this code on the browser that you'd see lines but they aren't showing on the map, although the code pulls accurate results from the rest API. It's been three days since I searched for solutions on this platform and I couldn't find any, hence this post.

What could I be missing here?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the logic in your code. After a couple of tweaks (replacing jquery's ajax with `fetch()`, renaming OSM), [it works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/pL4CjDlaNQGSrW4i).

Comment: Thanks Ivan, it works. Wish there was a way to make a tick alongside your answer by the way...